# mongo query to delete one doc with multiple conditions in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

```
db.LessonPlanConfiguration.deleteOne({'boardId' : ObjectId('5c270eec6c6d78001a206916') ,'gradeId' : ObjectId('5bc56a319fe946001a35d5d6') , 'topicId' : ObjectId('5c89de97d94fde0013b4983e')})
```

sample document :-

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ca654a5c60baf0017130d26"),
"instituteId" : ObjectId("5bdfdb4bfdd9360013c5f063"),
"academicSessionId" : ObjectId("5c271edf6c6d78001a209880"),
"branchId" : ObjectId("5be6655120a8040014ddae80"),
"learningLevelId" : ObjectId("5bac973268a260001ec442d1"),
"boardId" : ObjectId("5c26ed9032f6bf001d5ce14b"),
"gradeId" : ObjectId("5bc56a319fe946001a35d5d6"),
"sectionId" : ObjectId("5959d07732018df843695f9b"),
"subjectId" : ObjectId("5c30c4b465b0850014691563"),
"topicId" : ObjectId("5c3c0a5889c70900188b9c74"),
"startDate" : ISODate("2019-03-31T23:59:50.000+05:30"),
"endDate" : ISODate("2019-04-06T23:59:50.000+05:30"),
"totalSessions" : 7,
"lastUpdatedBy" : ObjectId("5a1b996690be901900bc2584"),
"lastUpdationTime" : ISODate("2019-04-05T00:31:57.907+05:30"),
"createdBy" : ObjectId("5a1b996690be901900bc2584"),
"creationTime" : ISODate("2019-04-05T00:31:57.907+05:30"),
"validFor" : 0,
"isArchived" : false
```

},

i have a collection in which i want to delete documents by matching 3 conditions like

1. boardId
2. gradeId
3. topicId

i am using this query to delete one doc from collection but this query does not deleting the documents what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: share your current sample document

Comment: added please check

Comment: your syntax seems to be correct, are you getting any error?

Comment: Is your matching condition correct, bcoz in your query `5c270eec6c6d78001a206916` does not match with document

Answer (score 0):

I think your matchig conditions are not right,
I was able to delete document with proper matching conditions

```
db.LessonPlanConfiguration.deleteOne({'boardId' : ObjectId("5c26ed9032f6bf001d5ce14b") ,'gradeId' : ObjectId("5bc56a319fe946001a35d5d6") , 'topicId' : ObjectId("5c3c0a5889c70900188b9c74")})
```

Or you can also ,Try using [Remove](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/)

```
db.LessonPlanConfiguration.remove({'boardId' : ObjectId("5c26ed9032f6bf001d5ce14b") ,'gradeId' : ObjectId("5bc56a319fe946001a35d5d6") , 'topicId' : ObjectId("5c3c0a5889c70900188b9c74")})
```